# No summary information in a pop-up window -- Option-Click

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode 10.2 , for example, when option-click the property "textLabel" in the code below , the pop-up window only shows Declaration.
I remembered Xcode was able to show Summary, Declaration, Discussion and also a link to its related reference document.

Does new Xcode change it ?

Is it still possible to get the link to documentation for the selected variable/property by option-click ?

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "aTableCell", for: indexPath)

cell.textLabel?.text = aArray[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Apple fixed it. Now Option-Click in 10.2 , just like 10.1, brings up Pop-Up Window that shows not only Declaration but also Summary, Discussion and the link to developer documentation.